# How is the Riemann-Siegel Z function evaluated in Mathematica?

Tags: special-functions, implementation-details

How is the Riemann-Siegel Z function evaluated in Mathematica?

Is it calculated using the first so many terms of its power series or by other means?

Comment: IIRC, it uses the Riemann-Siegel formula, as modified by [Odlyzko and Schönhage](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1988-0961614-2).